# Counting Grouped Rows By Where Clause MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I want to count the amount of people liked a post where a certain user liked that post.

```
Post:
Author - INT
Content - Text

Post_Like:
User_ID - Int
Post_ID - Int

SELECT p.content, count(pl.User_ID) FROM Post p JOIN Post_Like pl ON p.id = pl.Post_ID WHERE pl.User_ID = 40 group by pl.Post_ID
```

This is returning count 1 for each, which is wrong, but I am not sure how to count all the likes instead of only where the ID matches.

Comment: I have a feeling the query you used gives an error. You are selecting p.content, but grouping by Post_ID?

Comment: @VvdL yes! no error though

Comment: @VvdL grouping by Post_Like postID since I want to count the amount of likes that post has, but only where a certain user has liked that post

Comment: Ok, but you are using `WHERE pl.User_ID = 40`, so `count(pl.User_ID)` will obviously give you 1 as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT p.content, count(pl.User_ID) 
FROM Post p 
  JOIN Post_Like pl ON p.id = pl.Post_ID 
WHERE pl.Post_ID IN (
  SELECT u.Post_ID
  FROM Post_Like u
  WHERE u.User_ID = 40
)
GROUP BY p.content
```

Note that you need to list non-aggregate columns from SELECT in `GROUP BY` (ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql mode).